# How can I combine two Data Frames in Pandas Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames like below:

```
most_common_OMT = data["Order Method Type"].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).to_frame()
most_common_OMT
```

[image]

```
profitability_OMT = data.groupby("Order Method Type").agg({"Total Revenue":"mean"}).round(2).sort_values(by="Total Revenue",ascending=False)
profitability_OMT
```

[image]

And how can I combine these two tables so as to acheive DataFrame like below. It is not important what will be the index, simply I need to have table something like below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us just do

```
out = pd.concat([most_common_OMT, profitability_OMT], axis=1)
```